# Sensitivity/Specificity compared to Area Under Curve as measure of Screen Accuracy

Tags: auc, sensitivity-specificity

In relation to the disorder I'm studying Screen A is reported as having a sensitivity of 90% and a specificity of 89%. Screen B is reported as having a AUC of .79 with no other data provided. Could someone please explain the relative difference between these screens? I assume screen A is more useful but but by how much?

Comment: What Frank Harrell says is a valid criticism if you have the probability scores. I get the feeling that you're getting something like a physician's diagnosis of sick/healthy, so just the discrete outcome, not a probability. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to conclude much from these very limited data. For screen A you only have a point estimate at a given sensitivity/specificity combination. For screen B you have a summary measure for a ROC-curve of many Spec/Sens combinations. These measures are incomparable.

It also depends on what you see as the most "useful" screen, e.g. how many false positives/false negatives you are willing to tolerate. The two screens could be desirable under different requirements.

Comment: Sens and spec require the use of arbitrary cutpoints an are usually discouraged.  AUROC can be thought of as the $c$-index (concordance probability) and requires no cutoffs.  But also consider proper probability accuracy scores such as Brier.

Comment: @FrankHarrell in a concrete setting where you can attach (economic) losses to type I and type II errors it can be a good idea to fix either of them and optimize the other

Comment: Not in the least.  You can't attach a loss function to backwards time-order risks.  Minimizing expected losses comes from multiplying costs by direct probabilities of outcomes.

Comment: @FrankHarrell What about the [positive and negative predictive value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/502634/247274) you mention here? Those aren’t direct probabilities of outcomes, but the timing is in the correct order.

Comment: Yes in the right direction just not sufficiently conditional on covariates.